# Timeout onSubmit jquery display loader

Tags: javascript, jquery

Work perfectly on chrome and firefox but on safari my function `ShowLoading()` doesn't have the time to load , I want to put a little delay to onSubmit to let the time to my function to be called before the form is submitted!

```
<form onSubmit="setTimeout(function() { ShowLoading();}, 1);return true" method="post" 
      class="std" id="masterformer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested, but try this :

```
<form onSubmit="return function () { setTimeout(ShowLoading, 1); return true; }" method="post" 
  class="std" id="masterformer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```